# When is the compact-open topology compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ be the space of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ equipped with the compact open topology. What conditions do we need on $X$ and $Y$ to ensure that $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ is compact?

What I'm hoping is that if both $X$ and $Y$ are compact Hausdorff then these are sufficient conditions, but I'm unable to prove this. Perhaps there is an obvious counterexample to this that I'm missing?

**EDIT**: I found a counterexample, but maybe it can still work. Let $X = Y = S^1$. Then $\mathcal{C}(S^1, S^1)$ has infinitely many path components and so cannot be compact. But is each path component itself compact? That would still be useful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping spaces with the compact-open topology are virtually never compact.  In particular, for instance, suppose that there is a closed subspace $Z$ of $Y$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]$ and $X$ is normal and contains an infinite compact subset $K$.  (In particular, for instance, this holds whenever $X$ and $Y$ are nonempty positive-dimensional manifolds.)  Then $C(X,Z)$ is a closed subspace of $C(X,Y)$ and the restriction map $C(X,Z)\to C(K,Z)$ is surjective by the Tietze extension theorem.  So, if $C(X,Y)$ were compact, then $C(K,Z)$ would also be compact.  But $C(K,Z)\cong C(K,[0,1])$ is then just a subspace of the Banach space $C(K)$ of continuous real-valued functions on $K$ with the sup norm, and $C(K,[0,1])$ can in fact be described as the closed ball of radius $1/2$ centered at the constant function $1/2$ in $C(K)$. Since $K$ is infinite, $C(K)$ is infinite-dimensional, so closed balls in $C(K)$ are not compact.  Thus $C(K,[0,1])$ is not compact and neither is $C(X,Z)$ or $C(X,Y)$.  (Note in particular that $C(X,Z)$ is connected so this also shows that the connected component of $C(X,Y)$ containing $C(X,Z)$ is not compact.)

Some trivial cases where $C(X,Y)$ is compact are if $X$ is empty or if $Y$ is compact and $X$ is discrete (so the compact-open topology is just the product topology on $Y^X$) or if $Y$ is compact and every continuous map $X\to Y$ is constant (so $C(X,Y)\cong Y$).  Note that if $X$ is nonempty, then $C(X,Y)$ continuously surjects to $Y$ by evaluating at any point of $X$, so $C(X,Y)$ cannot be compact unless $Y$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! So if I understand correctly, even the connected components of $C(S^1,S^1)$ are not compact?

Comment: That's correct.