# Is the based path space of a compact space compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, say simply connected for simplicity. Let $x, y \in X$. Let
$$
E(X,x,y) = \{ f: [0,1] \to X : f(0) = x, f(1) = y  \}
$$
be the space of paths from $x$ to $y$, equipped with the compact-open topology. This is naturally a bounded metric space, under the supremum metric. My question is the following.

> What sort of conditions on $X$ make $E(X,x,y)$ compact? More generally what sort of conditions on a sequence $(p_n)$ in $E(X,x,y)$ imply that $(p_n)$ contains a convergent subsequence?

I've made some attempts at proving compactness but I'm not convinced by any of my own arguments and suspect some natural counterexamples exist. Secretly, I'm just interested in when a sequence of paths in a compact metric space approaches some sensible limit. Thank you!

Comment: Most of the times the space will not be compact, for example even for $X = [0, 1]$. For a sequence to have a convergent subsequence, you need equicontinuity - this is Ascoli’s theorem.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692673/when-is-the-compact-open-topology-compact

Comment: Never, unless every path is constant.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4390483 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4155232.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such space is never compact, unless $\{x=y\}$ is a path component (so $E(X,x,y)$ is a singleton) or there is no path from $x$ to $y$ (i.e. $E(X,x,y)=\emptyset$).

Otherwise, if $\{x,y\}$ belongs to a path component that has at least two points, then first of all I will assume that $x\neq y$. I can do this, because otherwise I will take a point $z\neq x$ and consider a path from $x$ to $z$ and then I will glue it with the inverse of itself. I will be looking at pointwise convergence, so with such operation only the first half will be of interest.

So assume that $x\neq y$ and we have a path $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$. Now define

$$f_n:[0,1]\to X$$
$$f_n(t)=f(t^n)$$

Now for fixed $t\in [0,1)$ we have $t^n\to 0$ and so $f_n(t)\to f(0)$. While $f_n(1)$ is constant and thus converges to $f(1)$. Since $f(0)\neq f(1)$, then this means that neither the sequence $f_n$ nor any of its subsequences are convergent to a continuous function.

*Side note:* the only interesting condition in this context that I know of is [the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) and its variants.